# How to use continue with Task in C# in If condition

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, async-await

I have implemented wcf client in my .NET application. My question is how I can ensure that if condition is call after Task> is completed?

```
  private List<MarketingCampaign> _GetAllCampaignTypeList()
    {
        List<MarketingCampaign> _MarketingCampaignList = null;

        Task<List<MarketingCampaignTypeData>> _MarketingCampaignTypeDataList = _MarketingCampaignTypeClientObject.GetAllCampaignTypes();

        ??? // how can I use continue with or Task.wait all in following if condition

        if(_MarketingCampaignTypeDataList!=null)
        {
           // code
        }

        return _MarketingCampaignList;
    }
```

### above code is calling following class

```
  public async Task<List<App.Client.Proxies.MarketingCampaignTypeServiceRef.MarketingCampaignTypeData>> GetAllCampaignTypes()
    {

        var task  = Task<List<App.Client.Proxies.MarketingCampaignTypeServiceRef.MarketingCampaignTypeData>>.Factory.StartNew(() => {
                                            return _MarketingCampaignTypeClient.GetAllCampaignTypes();
                                      });

        return await task.ConfigureAwait(false);

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to `await _MarketingCampaignTypeDataList`?

Comment: use .ContinueWith and put your check "if(_MarketingCampaignTypeDataList!=null)" inside .ContinueWith

Comment: I am new this thread programming so I am not really sure how to go about next step

Comment: I did await in calling class but not where I am calling from

Comment: Why do you check if task is null? It can't be null since you created it on the current scope

Comment: that is why I need to ensure that if is only called when thread is completed because then I also need to check that if I got data or not in list

Comment: Please, check out my answer. By using `await` you `if` will be executed only after task is completed.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need something like this:

```
async Task<List<MarketingCampaign>> GetAllCampaignTypeList()
{
    List<MarketingCampaign> campaignList = null;

    List<MarketingCampaignTypeData> campaignTypeList = await _MarketingCampaignTypeClientObject.GetAllCampaignTypes();

    if(campaignTypeList != null)
    {
       // do whatever you need to convert campaignTypeList to campaignList
    }

    return campaignList;
}
```

Also, you don't need `await` in `GetAllCampaignTypes` method, just return task. And I would suggest you to not use `Task.Factory.StartNew` without proper reason. Use `Task.Run` instead: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html

Comment: in await _MarketingCampaignTypeClientObject.GetAllCampaignTypes(); it says cannot convert system collection to task<system collection.. error

Comment: Maybe `GetAllCampaignTypes` returning List not a Task?